# calling GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this) from service

Tags: android

I need to get device Google messaging registration ID from service. however, when I call

```
GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)
```

from service, it complain that GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(service) is not applicable.

Is there away to get device registartion ID from a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to do it in a different way. Assuming your device is already registered, you can change your Service constructor to take Context as a parameter. That way your service will have the correct application context to pass to GCMRegistrar. If your service is bound, then you could always use ContextWrapper to get the same result.